# Laravel mocking model with persistence

Tags: php, laravel, mocking, phpunit

I'm testing a job that receives a customer model. In the job I create the
customer in shopify and store that id on the customer model. Then I call a `sendShopifyInvite` that needs to be mocked (I don't want to send an email in my test).

My test looks like this:

```
/** @test */
public function a_shopify_customer_is_created_if_it_does_not_yet_exists()
{
    $this->partialMock(User::class, function ($mock) {
        $mock->shouldReceive('sendShopifyInvite')->once()->andReturn(new User());
    });

    $customer = app(User::class)->fill(
        factory(User::class)->create([
            'shopify_id' => null
        ])->toArray()
    );

    $this->assertNull($customer->shopify_id);

    CreateCustomerJob::dispatchNow($customer);

    $customer->refresh();

    $this->assertNotNull($customer->shopify_id);
}
```

The problem is that I receive this error:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'jensssen_db.mockery_0__domain__customer__models__users' doesn't exist
```

Is it not possible to persist data in a mock object? Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is due to this [line](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a71964c452a4dfe3717686b0b96aa546d15f935f/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1298). Since a partial mocks creates a new mock object and calls your original model through it, it will take that class basename.

```
return $this->table ?? Str::snake(Str::pluralStudly(class_basename($this)));
```

I can see two solutions, i don't feel like anyone is the perfect solutions, it will solve your problem. Firstly set your table hardcoded on the `User.php` model. This will avoid the class basename being called.

```
class User {
    $protected table = 'users';
}
```

Another approach, i have been forced to make before (when you have a hard time mocking some classes). Is instead of mocking your `User.php` model, simply put the same logic in a service / proxy class and mock that instead.

```
class ShopifyService {
    public function sendInvite(User $user)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In your `User.php` model now have.

```
public function sendShopifyInvite() {
    resolve(ShopifyService::class)->sendInvite($this);
}
```

Now you are able to mock only the Shopify service and now not tinker with the inner workings of the Eloquent Model.

```
$this->partialMock(ShopifyService::class, function ($mock) {
    $user = new User();
    $mock->shouldReceive('sendInvite')->with($user)->once()->andReturn($user);
});
```